# how to get string value using this code

Tags: android

How to get string values using this,right now it return integer value.

```
 getApplicationContext(),getResources().getIdentifier("Please_Try_Again_"+nativeLocaleSymbol, "string", getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getIdentifier returns the resource identifier that why it is an int. Using the id you can get the resource

```
 int resId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("Please_Try_Again_"+nativeLocaleSymbol, "string", getPackageName());
 getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(resId)
```

Comment: it's work but i have modified it
        getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("loading_"+nativeLocaleSymbol, "string", getPackageName()));

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your application

```
    /**
     * Returns value of String from Android String identifier
     * 
     * @param id
     *            Android String identifier
     * @return Value of String identifier if argument is valid Android String
     *         identifier, same String passed in argument if not.
     */
    public static String getStringByFullIdentifier(final Context context,
            final String fullId) {
        String ret = fullId;
        final String id = StringHelper.getStringIdentifier(fullId);
        if (id != null) {
            ret = StringHelper.getStringByName(context, id);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    /**
     * Returns string resource by name. Consider using
     * {@link #getStringByName(String)} instead.
     */
    public static String getStringByName(final Context context,
            final String name) {
        final int intId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "string",
                context.getPackageName());
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = context.getString(intId);
        } catch (final NotFoundException e) {
            result = name;
        }
        return result;
    }
```